# React-Native | Problem with setState can't be read

Tags: javascript, android, api, react-native

The `setState` can't be read, the value of `print1` stays `0000` it must be changed to `array[0].date` and the alert shows the value of `array[0].date`
the problem is that it works before.

PS: there's no error shown

```
export default class WebServiceUse extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ({
            print1: '0000',
        })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://**********', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ id: '1' })
        }).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
            let array = responseJson.ed5aaf3d933385698d872d0a0d5d4f36
            alert(array[0].date)
            this.setState = ({
                print1: array[0].date,
            })
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Test:</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.print1}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.setState({ print1: array[0].date })`. You wrote an extra `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the state in the constructor, `this.state =` is assigning the initial value of the state object so it's not really a function.  Further down the lifecycle calling `this.setState` IS a function that merges existing state with your changes.  So change

```
        this.state = ({
        print1: '0000',
    })
```

to

```
        this.state = {
        print1: '0000'
    }
```

Also you're not assigning state, you're calling the function so don't use `=`

```
         this.setState = ({
         print1: array[0].date,
        })
```

ought to be

```
         this.setState({
         print1: array[0].date
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
export default class WebServiceUse extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ({
            print1: '0000',
        })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var that = this;
        fetch('https://**********', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ id: '1' })
        }).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
            let array = responseJson.ed5aaf3d933385698d872d0a0d5d4f36
            alert(array[0].date)
            that.setState({
                print1: array[0].date,
            })
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Test:</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.print1}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```